# Godot 3.1 WebGL context lost error using mobile browsers

Tags: webgl, mobile-browser, godot

I've built a game proof-of-concept using Godot 3.1 and exported it a a web assembly (wasm). The app runs fine with Firefox and Edge on Windows.

If I try to load the webpage using a mobile browser (Firefox or Chrome), the following error appears. Reloading the page gets the same error.

Am wondering if it is a memory or timeout problem. Loading takes 10+ seconds on a desktop browser.

The URL for the PoC page is in the error. Feel free to try it. Let me know if you get a different result. Maybe it is my Android phone that is the problem?

All ideas and suggestions are welcome. Many thanks in advance.

[image: WebGL Error]

Comment: Are you exporting with OpenGL 2 or 3? When exporting with OpenGL 3 it maps to WebGL 2 which is not maintained.

Comment: It works on my phone, though it took 30 seconds to load. I think you should check if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: What phone are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The WebGL problem was solved by changing to GLES2 (thanks to hola for the suggestion).

The long load time was due to exporting with debug turned on.